# Using push_back on vector allocated on the heap

Tags: c++, vector, heap-memory, c++98

I want to create a string vector inside a function and allocate memory for it on the heap. For this I am using

`vector<string>* residuetable = new vector<string>();`

When I then try to do

`&residuetable.push_back(modulo((exponentiate("2", exponent02)), modulus));`

i.e. try to add the return value from several function calls to the vector using the [push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) function, I get the compile time error

`request for member 'push_back' in 'residuetable', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >*`

How can I solve this problem and add the result of the function calls at the end of the vector allocated on the heap?

Comment: Dereference the pointer by using `*residuetable` instead (that is, if you want to keep the dot syntax).

Comment: @ChrisO: Or even better, `**&residuetable` to also keep the current code :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `->` to access class members via a pointer:

```
residuetable->push_back(...);
```

Then think again about whether you really want to be messing around with `new` at all. I'm quite sure you don't.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. If I want to allocate memory on the heap, what other way would I use instead of `new`? My understanding is that large data structures such as arrays should usually be allocated on the heap.

Comment: @ToshioYamaguchi: The point is that you _shouldn't_ be dynamically allocating vectors _at all_, generally.

Comment: @ToshioYamaguchi: The vector allocates its array on the heap - that's its purpose. You probably don't want the vector itself on the heap, unless you're doing something unusual with it. If you do have a good reason for that, then go ahead and do so; but do think about whether that's really what you want.

Comment: @ToshioYamaguchi vector does this for you **automatically**. When you add items to a vector space for them is allocated on the heap. There's no need to put the vector itself on the heap as well.

Answer (score 1):

You want: `residuetable->push_back("foo");`

Answer (score 1):

You used `&` instead of `*`, and `(*a).b` is the same as `a->b`:

```
residuetable->push_back("foo");
```

But generally we do not dynamically allocate containers as there are better ways to manage your data.